# possible for perl to print escape codes and not leave echo -n ""

Tags: perl

With many xterm's its nice to have a unique name on the window border that I can change on the fly. So I wrote this perl code in file header.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $saywhat = $ARGV[0];

my  $mycmnd = <<"EOLzippo";
echo -n "\033]0;XROSS\007"

EOLzippo

$mycmnd =~ s!XROSS!$saywhat!g;

print $mycmnd;
```

Then with an alias:

```
alias header 'perl ~/perl/header.pl \!* '
```

I can change the text at the top of my xterms.

When the alias is called the code leaves a echo-n on my command line:

```
163 perl> header test

echo -n ""
```

Is there a way to execute the print without leaving the echo -n ""?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to print echo (did you try to shell out and echo?). [print](http://p3rl.org/print) already prints.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $saywhat = shift;
my $string  = "\033]0;$saywhat\007";
print $string;
```

Comment: `"\033"` is `"\e"` and `"\007"` is `"\a"`

Comment: He *isn't* shelling out.  He's just printing (in a very complicated way) `echo -n "<escape code to change xterm title>"`.  The xterm interprets the escape codes; the rest are just printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

Do it *all* in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $saywhat = $ARGV[0];

my $mycmnd = "\033]0;${saywhat}\007"

print $mycmnd;
```

---

*Side note:* While it is a convention to use a `.pl` suffix sometimes, it is by no means mandatory. If you rename `header.pl` to `header` and put it in `~/bin` [or add `~/perl` to `$PATH`] you can eliminate the `alias`. Just be sure to set execute permissions on the file (e.g. `755`)